# SQL запрос из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql

В базе данных имеется таблица `USERS` с полями `<id>` и `<name>`, и таблица `USER_LOGINS` с полями `<user_id>` и `<login_time>`. Напишите SQL запрос, который получит выборку с полями `<user_name>`, `<login_time>` для строк `USER_LOGINS`.

Подскажите реализацию, пожалуйста.

Comment: Покажите как вы делаете выборку с одной таблицы!

Comment: И кажется вы вопрос недописали

Comment: Ну прежде чем задавать вопрос сперва можно убедиться что не задавали такой же,может на нго уже есть ответ . Пользуйтесь поиском https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86

Answer (score 0):

Используйте обычное [соединение таблиц](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html) `join`:

```
select u.name as user_name,
       ul.login_time
from users u
     join user_logins ul on u.id = ul.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `users`.`users_name`, `user_logins`.`login_time` 
FROM `users` 
JOIN `user_logins` 
  ON `users`.`users_id` = `user_logins`.`user_id`;
```